# Servicestack expecting lower assembly version

Tags: c#, .net, servicestack

If I try to use the JsonServiceClient of Servicestack I always get the following Exception:

> Could not load file or assembly 'ServiceStack.Text, Version=4.0.14.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.
>   System cannot find the file specified.":"ServiceStack.Text,
>   Version=4.0.14.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

The project runs with .net 4.5 and the Servicestack Version 4.0.15.0. That ist the weirdest thing, because I never had 4.0.14.0 as a reference. I only have a reference to Servicestack.Text 4.0.15.0 and all the other ServiceStack libs in 4.0.15.0

Before I had the same Problem with 3.9.66.0 expecting 3.9.63. But I upgraded via NuGet hoping to solve the Problem but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just noticed in my Outputfolder that Servicestack.Text was missing. Now I use a direct call to a class in Servicestack.Text and the compiler isn't optimising Servicestack.Text out.

Comment: You should update your question by editing it if you are still having problems.